# How to Change the Content of a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, f#

I am using FsXaml and was trying to change the content of a ContentControl as well as the content of a button on click of that button. What I have done so far is -

```
type MainView = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">
type UCon1 = XAML<"UC1.xaml">
type UCon2 = XAML<"UC2.xaml">

type MainViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()  

    let uc1 = new UCon1()
    let uc2 = new UCon2()

    let mutable buttonContent = "Beginning"
    let mutable content = uc1

    let canExecute(obj) = true
    let actionOnButtonClick(obj) = 
        match buttonContent with
        | "Beginning" -> self.ButtonContent <- "Ending"
                     //self.Content <- uc2 
        | _ -> self.ButtonContent <- "Beginning"
               //self.Content <- uc1

    member self.ButtonContent 
        with get () = buttonContent 
        and set value = buttonContent <- value
                        self.OnPropertyChanged "ButtonContent"

    member self.Content 
        with get () = content
        and set value = content <- value
                        self.OnPropertyChanged "Content"

    member x.ACommand = new RelayCommand(canExecute, actionOnButtonClick)
```

and in XAML -

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ACommand}" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}"/>
```

If I uncomment

```
self.Content <- uc2
```

I get an error in the setter of Content saying

```
This expression was expected to have type
    UCon1
but here has type
    UCon2
```

How to change the Content of that ContentControl?

Comment: You can't have two "different" types for a member, so you need to explicitely cast them to some common type

Comment: @Sehnsucht You are right. Thank You!

Comment: Why you don't use the `FsVM`?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I have found this [link](https://amazingant.com/blog/2014/12/08/FSharp-and-WPF/) which you referred in another question. I will go through it soon.

Comment: great, if you will have any question just ping me in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Comment: @FoggyFinder How to do that? Is it something like adding  `ping @FoggyFinder -t` statement below my question?

Comment: Oh! it probably is like mIRC @nick question will notify you right?

Answer (score 2):

It works -

```
let uc1 = new UCon1() :> obj
let uc2 = new UCon2() :> obj
```